# Incorrect display data in selectionchanged for combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In the XAML:

```
<Grid Background="White">
            <ComboBox  Grid.Row="0"
                        x:Name="BackTagBox"
                       ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                        DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                        SelectedValuePath="Id"
                        SelectionChanged="SelectionChanged" Margin="88,0,555,0"/>
            <ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding Sides}">

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Width="225px" Height="250px">
                            <StackPanel Name="Side" Width="225px" Height="250px">
                            <TextBlock Name="Name" Text="{Binding Path=Name}">
                            </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>

                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
```

In the Code Behind:

```
private void SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var List = (ComboBox)sender;
            var Item = (LabelBagItem)List.SelectedItem;

            if (selectedItem == null)
                return;

            foreach (var side in GetSides(Item.Id, Item.number))
            {
                Item.Sides.Add(sideWeight);
            }

        }
```

If I choose in ddl second and next items then data dont display althouh in the event it correctly add in `Item.Sides`.

data only display when I choose the first item

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of the property Sides to `ObservableCollection` instead of `List`.

This type will assure you, that the changes to the Collection are automatically notified to the UI, so that the changes are applied.

There are some information of your DataClass missing, so i can only guess.
You said the  it only works if you choose the first item:

--> Is the List "Sides" initially filled with the data of the first item, or is it filled from the event?

Comment: Sides is ObservableCollection<T>

Comment: List "Sides" is initialized with the data of the first item and second item, but dont display with the data of the second item

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code?, with the current example its hard to find the issue.